# Solutions to diagnose PDF files for exploits?

Tags: malware, chrome, pdf

**I am downloading a PDF file, and would like to know how to diagnose security vulnerabilities in that file.**

Context:

The last version of Google Chrome is giving me the following warning on a PDF download:

[image]

Trying to learn more about the alert brings me to [this help page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6261569?visit_id=1-636190141753332908-4275630444&p=ib_download_blocked&hl=en&rd=1), which explains that the alert can be triggered by either

> a malicious, unwanted, or uncommon file

or

> the website you tried to download the file from has been known to distribute malware.

I would like to sort out which one it is, and am therefore looking for a way to scan the PDF file for potential vulnerabilities.

My guess is that any tool that indicates the existence of executable code in the file would do, but does such a tool exist?

**Related:** [Can a PDF file contain a virus?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64052/can-a-pdf-file-contain-a-virus)

Comment: Upload the PDF to [VirusTotal](www.virustotal.com) if you can access it. If it is not flagged, then Chrome doesn't like the source; else it's the file (this is in fact, more likely).

Comment: See https://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/converting-untrusted-pdfs-into-trusted.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[peepdf](https://github.com/jesparza/peepdf) and [pdf-parser.py](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/) from Didier Stevens. [Various online malware scanners](https://github.com/rshipp/awesome-malware-analysis#online-scanners-and-sandboxes) which support PDF is good to try either.

Comment: Thank you very much. And your third link includes @Jedi's link to VirusTotal.

Comment: @Fr. Yes, VirustTotal is most well known in online malware scanners which anyone shouldn't forget to mention!