# Can flattened pdf documents contain viruses?

Tags: virus, pdf

While I came to this site from researching whether inactive (or flattened) PDF documents could contain viruses and have come across [this link in this 
 site](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64052/can-a-pdf-file-contain-a-virus), it does not answer my question.

I need to devise a strategy to flatten PDF documents to prevent active fields to inflict any harm. So, could a flattened PDF document still contain viruses and would these viruses become active when the document is opened?

Comment: Actually, the answers do also answer this question. If the PDF reader has a *vulnerability*, then it doesn't matter if the PDF is flattened or has active fields or not.

Comment: So, the best strategy would be, regardless of whether the document is flattened or has active fields, make sure it goes through an anti-virus, correct?

Comment: Well, the whole collection of protections, depending on the threat: AV, sandboxing, patching the PDF reader. There are tools that will re-write the PDF to only include the text content that *should* also remove any malware code in the PDF, too.